# page not found while running net5.0 web api project

Tags: docker, api, swagger, .net-5

I have a net5.0 web api project made using VS 2019 template that uses swagger to list the endpoints.
I have added container support to the project as well. All is well when I run the container from visual studio and it shows the swagger endpoints. Similarly it works fine while executing from visual studio as iis express or as a kestrel project.

The problem is when I build the dockerfile using:

```
docker build -t appnet5 -f .\ProjectName\Dockerfile .
```

And then run it:

```
docker run -d -p 4568:80 --name myapp appnet5
```

I get the error when trying to reach the endpoints saying:
**"This localhost page can't be found"**.

I tried reaching the swagger endpoint as well as the api endpoints. Both gives the same response.

Then I published the code using:

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

Then I ran the .exe application from the projectname\bin\Release\net5.0\publish folder.
Even though the application runs I am still getting the same error.

Here is a copy of the launchsettings:

```js
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63516",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "ProjectName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://0.0.0.0:80"
    }
  }
}
```

What might be the reason that I am not able to reach the endpoints and getting this error?
Am I approaching the issue wrong?
Thank you

Comment: can you **cd** to project folder(where csproj lies) and run `docker build -t appnet5  .`